# How to select GitLab CI job on creating or merging MR

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to have the possibility of running different tasks (selected task) on merge request.
How can I configure .gitlab-ci.yml/GitLab CI Settings to have such possibility?

```
deploy_test:
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploying ..."

deploy_test_v2:
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploying ..."
  when: manual

deploy_test_v3:
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo "Deploying ..."
  when: manual
```

I would like to chose which of the three will be invoked automatically on merging. For now `deploy_test` is invoked automatically on merging always; `deploy_test_v2` and `deploy_test_v3` can be invoked manually after. This is not what I want.

---

By other words:

I have 3 jobs for `test` server:

1. Full deployment with getting `staging` DB.
2. Deployment without getting `staging` DB.
3. Only CSS compilation.

I would like to give a possibility to a developer to select which job will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/):

```
build:
  stage: build
  script: ./build
  only:
  - merge_requests
```

Comment: Amityo, if I have  several `only: - merge_requests` how to select which one I want to perform.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have 3 jobs for `test` server:

1. Full deployment with getting `staging` DB.
2. Deployment without getting `staging` DB.
3. Only CSS compilation.

I would like to give a possibility to a developer to select which job will be performed.

Comment: have a look at this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html